# Restricting Amazon QuickSight Analysis creation with specific names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight, aws-iam-policy

I am working with Amazon QuickSight, and I would like to restrict the creation of QuickSight analyses with specific names (in my case: string finishing by: " ***analysis***"). In other words, I want to deny **all** quicksight devs from creating analyses with names that match this pattern.

Here's an example of an IAM policy statement I've tried:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "quicksight:CreateAnalysis",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "quicksight:AnalysisName": [
                        "* analysis"                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But it fails with error that "quicksight:AnalysisName" is not recognized.

Would be happy to find a way to enforce this kind of restriction using AWS IAM policies, or using any other approach to achieve this in Amazon QuickSight?